# How to add old version Qt Multimedia Module to qt 5x manually?

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

I've been dealing with a github project for 5 days. The project was done a few years ago. But one feature of this project was made with an old version of QtMultimedia. Currently not working. I found qt multimedia 5.4.3 on github (its old version) I need to manually add the old 5.4.3 version of Qtmultimedia to Qt software. Even though I added it according to the instructions, I still encounter the following errors. (Please don't tell me to update the project to work with the new version of Qtmultimedia. I'm not that professional. Also im working on windows platform.This project was made with qt 5.x version.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/tAyhb.png

When I add the qtmultimedia module manually, it does not detect the directory of the module in the invocation process like #include . I'm getting a "file not found" error. In addition, qtmultimedia files do not see each other within themselves.

```
code that works with an example legacy qtmultimedia. The QAbstractVideoSurface class is obsolete. When I add the qtmultimedia module manually, the module cannot even call its own classes (not found error). qtmultimedia no longer offers version 5.4.3 "qt maintance" software either.
```

Comment: Porting Qt5's QtMultimedia module to work with Qt6 is likely to be more difficult than updating the application's codebase to use the Qt6 version of QtMultimedia.  If you can't manage the latter, I suggest hiring someone who can; it shouldn't take very long.

Comment: thanks for answer. I installed qt 5 on my computer. it doesn't matter so I can use any version of qt for this. But I couldn't load it into qt 5, the old version of the qt multimedia module. When I load it, as I said above, when I call multimedia classes into qt as include, it does not see the classes of the module. I also tried qt creator 5x. So I can't successfully install the module manually. @JeremyFriesner

Comment: Your problem might be as simple as adding the line `QT += multimedia` to your .pro file.

Comment: I already added it. I didn't even do the project myself. The person who made the project already added it because he used the multimedia module the year he produced this project. Of course he should have added it. I've been trying for 4 days just to integrate the qt multimedia module into qt, so I tried many things.